# Cryptic Country 4

Tags: riddle, knowledge, limerick

I have northen football that can unite

A flying city that will always fight

Festive in the south

A big man with a mouth

And mistaken as the greater might

Name the country

Hint 1

> The greater might refers to different countries making a bigger country

Comment: Is the answer the USA?

Comment: No, it is not the USA, but I see why you might think that.

Comment: Is the country part of the un?

Comment: Kind of, again, you'll see why I say that once you get the answer

Comment: Is "northen" a typo for "Northern"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> England

I have northen football that can unite

> Manchester is in northern England, and has a football club called United

A flying city that will always fight

> Not sure about this one. London is one of Europe's premier air traffic hubs, and Londoners are [notorious for football-related violence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Upton_Park_riot) (although I suppose that applies to the English in general).

Festive in the south

> Southern England has popular vacation spots (Brighton, Eastbourne, Torbay)

A big man with a mouth

> Jason Bourne is a big man, Bournemouth is a city in England

And mistaken as the greater might

> Sometimes mistakenly used as a synonym for the UK as a whole

Comment: Yep, I was asking to be really specific, which is why Great Britain was wrong. Good job

Answer (score 2):

Is the country

> Republic of Ireland?

I have northen football that can unite

> Northern Ireland and ROI had a joint football association till around 1921, when it split.

A flying city that will always fight

> Could be Dublin, because of the Civil War. Not sure about the flying part.

And mistaken as the greater might

> Republic of Ireland is commonly mistaken to be a part of the UK.

Also,

> One of ROI's biggest cities is Limerick :P

Comment: It is not Ireland. Also, Northern Ireland and the Republic of Ireland are two different countries

Comment: Commonly mistaken... whaa?

Comment: It is a common misconception outside Europe. Many people don't even know that there are two separate countries.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is it

   > Catalonia?

Because of

> being seen as a part of Spain

and

> being united by football.

2. My only other guess was

> Britain

but that's only because the riddle made me think of

> Manchester United.

Comment: One of them is partially correct, the answer you said is more of an island, not a country

Comment: The first answer I gave is disputed, to be fair. But people there might consider themselves a separate country. But it's def not an island. The second answer is both an island and a country in my opinion, though, so I'm a little confused by your last comment.

Comment: I can see that, but the hints attempted to specify one part of the island. Also, when people say that is a country, they usually refer to the whole United Kingdom, not the island. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> Norway

I have northern football that can unite

> Nordic Football Championship

A flying city that will always fight

> Valhalla or Asgard

A big man with a mouth

> Thor?

And mistaken as the greater might

> Vikings?

Comment: No, it is not Norway

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Great Britain?

That seems to make sure sense to me than the

> UK

Edit to respond to comment without spoiler:

> Hmm, my understanding has always been that Britain, Wales, Scotland, Isle of Man sort of, etc are all their own nations within the United Kingdom. I guess I'll just wait to see what the correct answer is and see gone it's different from Britain or Great Britain or UK. I guess it could be Scotland or Wales but that doesn't make any sense as far as the clues.

Oh! Just realized I never said

> England!

Comment: It is part of this, and technically that isn't a country, it's the big island next to the Ireland Island

Comment: Not sure how to discuss spoilers in comments so I'll edit my answer

Comment: Okay, you can do that if you want

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> The Netherlands?

It probably has a football team called United in the north and

> Holland is often mistaken for the whole country.

Comment: Nope, but good guess